# how to remove duplicates from coalesce

Tags: postgresql

I have a query in postgres below

```
SELECT coalesce(dl.emp_id, um.id) id,
       um.emp_name,
       dl.project_id,
       sum(dl.worked_hours)AS total
FROM tools_tracker.projects_master pm
FULL JOIN tools_tracker.daily_log dl ON dl.id=pm.id
FULL JOIN tools_tracker.users_master um ON dl.emp_id=um.id
AND dl.date BETWEEN '2019-04-23' AND '2019-04-26'
AND um.role='Development_Team'
GROUP BY COALESCE(dl.emp_id, um.id),
         um.emp_name,
         dl.project_id,
         dl.worked_hours
ORDER BY um.emp_name ASC
```

Which gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnvy4.png) as the resulting output

How to remove the duplicates from the id columns?

please let me know, 
thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove `dl.worked_hours` from `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY COALESCE(dl.emp_id, um.id),
         um.emp_name,
         dl.project_id
```